# Bash/MLT : how to load string from file and passing to melt argument

Tags: bash, mlt, melt-framework

I need to execute the following command :

```
melt color:"#eeeeee"  -filter dynamictext:"this text"
```

`"this text"` is a string from a `title.txt` file.

I read the file by using this method:

```
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
     echo $line 
done < "title.txt"
```

The problem is how to make `-filter dynamictext:"this text"` in bash loop as string and then finally execute:

```
melt color:"#eeeeee" $string
```

I used this code but with no luck so far:

```
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
   string="$string -filter dynamictext:\"$line\""
done < "title.txt"
```

melt error : `Failed to load "text"`

`title.txt` contains:

```
this text
second text
anothe text
```

Comment: Escape the quote: `"$string -filter dynamictext:\"$line\""`

Comment: thank, but doesnt work..
video output : "this and generate error
Failed to load "text""

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: does `"-filter dynamictext:'$line'"` work?  (Double quotes on the outside with single quotes on the inside.)

Comment: not work, video output : 'this, console error : Failed to load "text"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an array; this is the exact use case they were introduced to handle.

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    options+=(-filter dynamictext:"$line")
done < title.txt
melt color:#eeeeee "${options[@]}"
```

Fix `title.txt` so that it correctly ends with a newline.